# How to change the "generate steps definition" template for cucumber for typescript in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I use Gherkin / Cucumber in my e2e tests for my Angular (Typescript) project and Intellij has this nice feature fo generating the template code for the step definitions (alt-enter).

How can I change these templates?

[image: generate steps definition]

When I generate the step I get this:

```
Then(/^foo$/, function() {

});
```

but I want it to generate this:

```
Then(/^foo$/, async () => {

});
```

I have searched in the `File and Code Templates` section and in the `Life Templates` but can't seem to find any template responsible for these generations.

It is driving me to distraction :-) please help.

Answer (score 0):

These templates are hardcoded and can't be customized.
If you miss a possibility to create custom templates for step definitions, please file a feature request to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)